# Cannot run Android apps with eclipse on OS X 10.6

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, osx-snow-leopard

Running Eclipse 3.5.2 (Classic) in OS X 10.6.7 with the ADT plugin. I have the SDK installed and have run the SDK and AVD Manager to install all available platforms and tools. I have an AVD setup with Android 2.2 as the target API, and have configured the example 'Hello, Android' app for Android 2.1 Update 1, so compatibility should not be an issue. When I Run the application, it starts up the emulator, but gives me an error before the android startup animation appears. Here is the output in the Console window of Eclipse:

```
[2011-04-10 06:45:40 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2011-04-10 06:45:40 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-04-10 06:45:40 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-04-10 06:45:40 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.twopoint7.testing.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-04-10 06:45:40 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'testDroid'
[2011-04-10 06:45:40 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'testDroid'
[2011-04-10 06:46:04 - Emulator] 2011-04-10 06:46:04.613 emulator[997:903] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
[2011-04-10 06:46:04 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-04-10 06:46:04 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-04-10 06:47:22 - HelloAndroid] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.twopoint7.testing.HelloAndroid activity launch'!
```

Any advice on what might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated. I've found lots of posts (here and on other forums) that seem to indicate the NSQuickDrawView vs. Quartz warning seems to be a problem across the board but doesn't have a solution yet. I'm more concerned with the "emulator-5554 disconnected..." bit and the fact that I can't seem to run any apps in the emulator. Any other info I can provide which would be helpful? Any insight?
Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to reset your adb after launch the emulator. In eclipse, go to **window -> show view -> other -> device(under android folder)**.
In the device view, find and reset adb. Then run your apps.